# Sampling combinations

Tags: sampling, simulation, combinatorics

I'm running a simulation where the different inputs are combinations of $n$ values taken in  $r$. The problem is that even though $n$ is small, the number of different combinations is very large, so I would need to randomly sample the different cases. For example, I need to run simulations for $\binom{16}{3}$, $\binom{16}{4}$...$\binom{16}{8}$ and I have to compare the results of the different combinations of inputs. What's the best approach for sampling these combinations? Which random distribution may I use? How many samples should I take for each of them so the results are comparable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second question has no general answer: you would need to give us the particulars of the simulation. As far as the sampling method goes, one solution for sampling without replacement is available by modifying my solution for sampling permutations at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24713 (for which working `R` code is provided). (Sampling *with* replacement is almost trivially easy, so I presume that's not what you need.)

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful. Yes, the second one is not general, in my case it should be uniform sampling. But the third one, do you think I should obtain a number of samples proportional (or logarithmic maybe) to the number of combinations (but less than the total of course)?

Comment: It depends on what the simulation is doing with them.  In general, the answer could literally be anything from zero through the entire set of combinations.