# How to put priors on permutation matrices for "permutation regression"?

Tags: regression, stochastic-ordering

## Background

I would like to put prior probabilities over permutation matrices $\mathbf{P}$

$$\vec A = \mathbf{P} \vec B$$

where $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are the same random vectors up to a permutation (hence the equality above).

The motivation for the problem is to learn from data the distribution of ways that data gets reordered by a process.

I have another soft constraint. I don't want the priors to be really strong. I don't mind if some permutation matrices a slightly more likely than others, but I don't want the model to strongly prefer specific permutation matrices in the priors. Sorry that is vague, but I couldn't quite define exactly how weak is weak enough.

---

## Attempt

### Bernoulli Entries

My first naive attempt is to assign that $p_{ij} \sim \text{Binomial}\left(1, \frac{1}{2} \right)$, but this ignores the constraint every row and column has only one non-zero value.

### Correlated Entries

A next step could be to model that deeper dependence using a multivariate normal and a sigmoid (or similar) to predict the probability parameters for the binomial. But this still only probabilistically would give me permutation matrices. A quickly-contrived first approximation of this approach might look like this:

$$p_{ij} \sim \text{Binomial}\left(1, \theta_{i,j} \right)$$

$$\theta_{i,j} := \text{sigmoid}(\tau_{ij})$$

($\tau_{ij}$ is an element of a random matrix $\mathbf{T}_{n \times n}$)

$$\mathbf{T}_{n \times n} \sim \text{MvNormal}(\mathbf{M}_{n \times n}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{n^2 \times n^2})$$

### Ordinal Regression

It occurred to me that I could do an [ordered regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) where I ordered logit transform both the predictor and predicted variables, but I am unsure how that gets me the permutation matrices I want at the end.

---

## Question

How can I put priors on the permutation matrices so that the row/column constraint is necessarily satisfied?

Comment: If you want a low-information prior (depending on what you're doing with the prior/how the prior is entering into your calculations), you could put a uniform prior on them, since it would then just be $\frac{1}{m}$ (where $m$ counts the number of possible $P$'s) - which is just a scaling constant. If you explain where that causes you a difficulty, that might clarify what the issue really is. The problem I expect would tend to be more with "how do I label my permutations" to keep track of the posterior probabilities which isn't really a problem with the prior ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... though if you want a non-uniform prior, you run into the labelling issue at the "specify the prior" stage.

Comment: @Glen_b I see what you are saying. Indeed the above approaches try to avoid explicitly labeling the permutation matrices because there will be $n!$ of them. Any approach that explicitly labels the permutation matrices will only work for very small $n$, which on my laptop I suspect limits me to $n < 7$. But I need something more like $n \in [2,100]$. So the difficulty is in assigning priors that can scale reasonably with $n$.

Comment: Again, if you used the flat prior I mentioned, where in the approach that you're using would that prior lead to a problem? It's not clear how to help if I don't follow where the problem hits.

Comment: @Glen_b You're suggesting a uniform prior over the set of permutation matrices, which would imply that each permutation matrix has a probability of $\frac{1}{n!}$ where $n$ is the dimension. In pure math that is fine, but I don't understand how I could practically do that when $n=100$. That would imply $100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000$ labels. Instead I am hoping define priors on the entries of $\mathbf{P}$ which satisfy the constraints of a permutation matrix.

Comment: @Glen_b So where the problem hits is the computational feasibility, not whether there exists a uniform distribution in pure math. Does that clarify?

Comment: It's dead simple to generate random permutations with uniform probability.  Moreover, it's not hard to construct (explicitly and efficiently) a one-to-one map from the integers $\{0,1,\ldots, n!-1\}$ (which in turn can be identified with the Cartesian product $\{0\}\times \{0,1\}\times \cdots\times\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$) to the set of permutations of $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}.$ Thus, *any distribution on the first set* answers your question.  However, it's unclear what you are referring to by "row/column" constraint: could you explain that?  Is this a constraint on the support of the prior?

Comment: @whuber re "row/column" constraint: I was referring to the defining characteristic of a permutation matrix that it has exactly one "1" in every row and column.

Comment: @whuber Conveniently, using a uniform prior involves using $Pr(\mathbf{P}) = \frac{1}{n!}$ for any $\mathbf{P}$. How would I then efficiently keep track of the $100!$ probabilities in the posterior? These will not be uniform, in general, and storing an array of $100!$ $\texttt{float32}$ numbers in memory is a no-go.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "keep track of," because nobody represents a distribution by means of a complete enumeration of its support.  (How would you deal with distributions with infinite support, for instance?)  As far as keeping track of a *sample* of permutations goes, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24300 for solutions.   (The one I posted requires $O(n\log n)$ time to generate a permutation.) It sounds like you have some kind of algorithm in mind that you haven't yet disclosed.  What is it?

Comment: @whuber "*nobody represents a distribution by means of a complete enumeration of its support.*" Well, certainly we do when the support is small enough. But we strongly agree that isn't a viable option in this context.

Comment: @whuber I have not looked at the algorithm you referenced yet, but I trust it is efficient for implicitly generating permutation matrices from integers. That isn't the issue. ... ctd

Comment: It is efficient for keeping track of all the permutations that have been generated.

Comment: @whuber Ah, I see. So if I take 2000 samples from the posterior I need only store no more than 2000 distinct integers. That is feasible. I'll have to think more on how to change my PyMC code, but that isn't a stats question.

Comment: Note that if you're considering sample sizes on the order of 2000 and $n$ greater than $10$ or so, you don't have to worry about detecting collisions: they will be inconsequentially rare.  The only data structure you will need then is an array (of fixed, predictable size).  Other data structures might be more useful and efficient depending on how you plan to analyze the posterior distribution, but might not be worth the time to implement unless this will be extensively-used production code.